# antd Tooltip- transitionName vs motion - How to get the same behavior?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I was able to remove the transition by setting `transitionName` to `''` but `transitionName` is deprecated and it's advised to use `motion` instead. I can't seem to get the same behavior when I use:

```
motion={{
    motionName: ''
}}
```

Playgound:

[image: Edit on CodeSandbox]

I also tried getting playing around with the other `motion` props but I can't get the desired behavior.

The behavior I get using `motion={{ motionName: ''}}` (there is still some animation):
[image: CPT2304141202-786x233]

The behavior I want (using `transitionName=''`):
[image: CPT2304141201-786x233]